# Weights in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-compose-layout

Is it possible to do weights in Jetpack Compose? For example, I'd like to set it up in such a way that one item is weighted as 1/3 of a layout, and the other takes up the remaining 2/3.

In the XML/ViewGroup style, you can achieve this using LinearLayouts and ConstraintLayouts. To my dismay, however, it doesn't seem possible using Jetpack Compose.

**Example**:

In ConstraintLayout, this is done as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/blue"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/red"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In LinearLayouts, this is done as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know that you can use Tables to get *evenly* distributed things, but I want an *uneven* distribution.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should “accept” the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 141):

You can use the [**`Modifier.weight`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#weight)
Something like:

```
Row() {
    Column(
        Modifier.weight(1f).background(Blue)
    ){
        Text(text = "Weight = 1", color = Color.White)
    }
    Column(
        Modifier.weight(2f).background(Yellow)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Weight = 2")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: for those fanatics like me, that really want to avoid nested layouts, compose is not affected by this!

Comment: @desgraci You can use `weight(0f)` or you can just omit the `weight` modifier.

Answer (score 13):

Since "0.1.0-dev09" modifiers are moved on an interface, you can use

> Modifier.weight(float, boolean)

to divide the vertical/horizontal space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight

```
 Column {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(2.0f, true)) {
            Box (
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(),
                backgroundColor = Color.Red
            )
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f, true)) {
            Box (
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(),
                backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                gravity = ContentGravity.Center
            ) {
                Text(text = "A sample text")
            }
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(2.0f, true)) {
            Box (
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(),
                backgroundColor = Color.Yellow
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: The default value is true, so you don't need so specify it

Comment: How do I know how much high should be weight of my views? Let's say I have a column with three objects. The second one takes the most part of layout so that the first and the last objects have the default height and the second one should fill the place between the first and last one. In XML you could put those objects in `LinearLayout` and set the weight of the second view to 1. How do I achieve that in in Jetpack compose? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "0.1.0-dev04" release of Jetpack Compose contains changes, and **FlexRow** is deprecated. I can propose the following solution:

```
Row {
    Card(modifier = LayoutFlexible(1f), color = Color.Red) {
        Container(expanded = true, height = 50.dp) {

        }
    }
    Card(modifier = LayoutFlexible(2f), color = Color.Green) {
        Container(expanded = true, height = 50.dp) {

        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

The **LayoutFlexible(flex = _f)** helps us to solve the issue and Modifier can be applied to any container.

Answer (score 1):

Use Modifier.weight(float) on the objects inside a container.
You could also use constraintlayout or the Low Level `Layout` Composable. Check out the official compose layout codelab in compose pathways for more info on the same

Answer (score 1):

***Here is an example from my project on using weights***

**Composables**

```
@Composable
fun PokemonAttributes(
    pokemonWeight: Int,
    pokemonHeight: Int,
    sectionHeight: Dp = 80.dp
) {
    val weight = remember { weightHeightMeasurement(pokemonWeight) }
    val height = remember { weightHeightMeasurement(pokemonHeight) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        PokemonDetailDataItem(
            dataValue = weight,
            dataTag = stringResource(id = R.string.str_weight),
            dataUnit = stringResource(id = R.string.str_kg),
            dataIcon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_pokemon_weight),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .size(1.dp, sectionHeight)
            .background(Color.LightGray))
        PokemonDetailDataItem(
            dataValue = height,
            dataTag = stringResource(id = R.string.str_height),
            dataUnit = stringResource(id = R.string.str_meter),
            dataIcon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_pokemon_height),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun PokemonDetailDataItem(
    dataValue: String,
    dataTag: String,
    dataUnit: String,
    dataIcon: Painter,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    val iconSize : Dp = 50.dp
    val attributeSpacing : Dp = 8.dp
    val attributeValueSize = 18.sp
    val attributeTagSize = 12.sp
    val displayText = "$dataValue $dataUnit"

    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = dataIcon,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(iconSize),
            tint = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = displayText,
                fontFamily = Nunito,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = attributeValueSize,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
            )
            Text(
                text = dataTag,
                fontFamily = Nunito,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                fontSize = attributeTagSize,
                color = Color.LightGray
            )
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Row() {
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = modifier.weight(1f).clickable {

        },
        value = formatDate(date) ?: "",
        onValueChange = {  },
        label = { Text("Date") },
        singleLine = true,
        readOnly = true
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = modifier.weight(1f),
        value = formatTime(date) ?: "",
        onValueChange = {  },
        label = { Text("Time") },
        singleLine = true
    )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Compose transforms the state into UI elements.

Composition of elements
Layout of elements
Drawing of elements

Standard layout components

```
@Composable
fun ArtistCard() {
    Column {
        Text("Alfred Sisley")
        Text("3 minutes ago")
    }
}
```

Similarly, use Row to place items horizontally on the screen. Both Column and Row support configuring the alignment of the elements they contain.

```
  @Composable
    fun ArtistCard(artist: Artist) {
        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Image(/*...*/)
            Column {
                Text(artist.name)
                Text(artist.lastSeenOnline)
            }
        }
    }
```

Use Box to put elements on top of another. Box also supports configuring specific alignment of the elements it contains.

```
@Composable
fun ArtistAvatar(artist: Artist) {
    Box {
        Image(/*...*/)
        Icon(/*...*/)
    }
}
```