# Jetpack Compose Android TextField exceeding width and pushing right element to get cramped up

Tags: android, textfield, word-wrap, android-jetpack-compose

```
TextField(
    value = newCommentState.value,
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
    ),
    onValueChange = { newCommentState.value = it },
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        backgroundColor = Color.White
    ),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences),
    placeholder = {
        Text(
            "Add your comment",
            color = colorResource(R.color.disabled_gray)
        )
    }
)
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
ClickableText(
    modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(70.dp),
    text = AnnotatedString("Post"),
    style = TextStyle(
        color = if (newCommentState.value.text.isNullOrEmpty())
            colorResource(
                R.color.disabled_gray
            ) else colorResource(R.color.green),
        fontSize = 20.sp,
    ),
    onClick = {
        if (newCommentState.value.text.isNullOrEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Cant post empty comment!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        else
            coroutineScope.launch { createComment(context) }
    },
)
```

I have written this code for a textfield that takes in user comments and has a Clickable Text "Post" next to it. The text "Post" gets pushed and wrap when the textfield has text outside the width.

[image]

I want the text to get wrapped without hitting the "Post" .

Comment: Maybe you could use constraint layout

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by adding `Modifier.weight(1f)` to your `TextField`. From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)):

> The parent will divide the horizontal space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight.

Answer (score 1):

You may either give your views the proper weight like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651653/2490594) answer as an example or you can only give the TextField only weight, and the other views to be without weight which as per documentation will do the below quote .

> The parent will divide the horizontal space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight