# JetPack Compose - weight() in Row in Card doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When creating an Android app, I put some Composables in a Row of a Card, as shown below, and it did not work as I expected. The Composable that I put "weight(1f)" on was no longer showing up.

```kotlin
data class Test(
    val title: String,
    val text: String
)

@Composable
fun CardRowSample(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val testList =
        listOf(
            Test("AAAA", "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"),
            Test("BBBB", "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20")
        )

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
         items(
             items = testList
         ) {
             test ->
                Card(
                    elevation = 12.dp,
                    backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .heightIn(min = 50.dp)
                        .width(40.dp)
                        .requiredHeight(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)
                        .padding(
                            horizontal = 20.dp,
                            vertical = 20.dp
                        )
                        .border(
                            width = 1.dp,
                            color = Color.Black,
                            shape = RectangleShape
                        )
                ) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {

                        Icon(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
                                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Check,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )

                        Text(
                            text = test.title,
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            modifier =
                            Modifier
                                .width(120.dp)
                                .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 10.dp)
                        )

                        Text(
                            text = test.text,
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)//it doesn't work!!
                                .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 10.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**My ideal image of the layout:**

[image]

---

I wrote the code referring to the following question, [Weights in Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58650272/weights-in-jetpack-compose), but I can't figure out why this is happening. I put "weight" on everything and added fillParentMaxSize to the Row's modifier, but I wasn't able to solve this problem.

What should I do next to solve this problem?

Comment: Try Removing `width` and `requiredHeight` attributes from Card Composable . And make your Row fill mas Size with `verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is not with `Modifier.weight(1f)`. It's because of `Modifier.requiredHeight(IntrinsicSize.Min)`

```
Card(
    elevation = 12.dp,
    backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .heightIn(min = 50.dp)
//                    .width(40.dp)
//                    .requiredHeight(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .padding(
            horizontal = 20.dp,
            vertical = 20.dp
        )
        .border(
            width = 1.dp,
            color = Color.Black,
            shape = RectangleShape
        )
)
```

Also Modifier.width(40.dp) is redundant because you have another width modifier `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` before that.

When Modifier.requiredIn with Intrinsic size modifiers act strange. Composable gets measured twice and with Infinity constraints

```
LAYOUT constraints: Constraints(minWidth = 0, maxWidth = 1080, minHeight = 0, maxHeight = Infinity), width: 1080, height: 235
LAYOUT constraints: Constraints(minWidth = 0, maxWidth = Infinity, minHeight = 235, maxHeight = 235), width: 510, height: 235
```

That's the second measurement breaks width because of `maxWidth = Infinity`. 1080px is full width on my device

to see Constrains and Composable width and height you can use

```
Card(
    elevation = 12.dp,
    backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .heightIn(min = 50.dp)
//                    .width(40.dp)
                    .requiredHeight(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            println("LAYOUT constraints: $constraints, width: ${placeable.width}, height: ${placeable.height}")
            layout(placeable.width,placeable.height){
                placeable.placeRelative(0,0)
            }
        }
        .padding(
            horizontal = 20.dp,
            vertical = 20.dp
        )
        .border(
            width = 1.dp,
            color = Color.Black,
            shape = RectangleShape
        )
)
```

Comment: I have no idea why it happens though with required and Intrinsic combined. If you change to `height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)` you get `Constraints(minWidth = 1080, maxWidth = 1080, minHeight = 235, maxHeight = 235)` and full width. Intrinsic sizes call layout twice but why with Infinity when requiredHeight is set i have no clue

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the [Thracian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73643865/2016562) is to apply `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` to your `Card` and `fillMaxHeight()` to the `Icon`.

```
    Card(
        elevation = 12.dp,
        backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(min = 50.dp)
            .height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .padding(
                horizontal = 20.dp,
                vertical = 20.dp
            )
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                color = Color.Black,
                shape = RectangleShape
            )
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {

            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Check,
                contentDescription = null
            )

            Text(
                text = test.title,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier =
                Modifier
                    .width(120.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 10.dp)
            )

            Text(
                text = test.text,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 10.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]