# `weight`-modifier makes composable vanish

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73643459/20806524), but I didn't quite understand what was wrong in the end, and since I don't use `requiredHeight` I don't know what to fix. But it's maybe the same issue: Without the `weight`-modifier set the text shows up, with it it vanishes:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ToiletItem(indexedToilet: IndexedValue<Toilet>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val toilet = indexedToilet.value
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Card(modifier = modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded }) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(12.dp)
                    .weight(1f),
            ) {
                Text(
                    "${indexedToilet.index + 1}.",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.displaySmall,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                )
                Text(
                    stringResource(R.string.toilet),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                )
            }
            if (expanded) Text(
                stringResource(toilet.textRes),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(12.dp)
                    .weight(3f),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
            )
            Image(
                painterResource(toilet.imageRes),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
                alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[weight declared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sahN0.png)

```kotlin
Card(modifier = modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded }) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(12.dp)
                    //.weight(1f),
            ) {
...
```

[weigth not declared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBvTY.png)

The height of the card is set by it's container `LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid`.

Maybe setting weight isn't the right way at all because the container wraps around the content, so it doesn't need to distribute the space? But then, how am I going to have the second, collapsible, text element beeing n times as wide as the first?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to put a weight on the image as well; if not, the image overtakes the entire view, so the text won't show up